# Display Dialog on App's first load and Handling Orientation Changes

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I currently confused on how I can display my dialog only if the application is first time to load only with orientation change. I have only one activity composed of tabs.

Problem:

I tried using `boolean` variables and `preferences` but I can't figure out on where to place them in cases where the activity's view is being destroyed. Destroyed is either by exiting the app or orientation change. Secondly, during orientation changes the dialog should be showed again on first time, but the even if I *dismiss* dialog and *do* orientation change - the dialog is displayed again which should not happen. I prefer not using the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)`.

```
 boolean FirstTimeActivityOpened = true;
 boolean dialogDismissed = false;
     boolean orientationChanged = false;
```

++++++++++

```
if(FirstTimeActivityOpened && dialogDismissed && orientationChanged ){
  loadDialog(this);
}

    new OrientationEventListener(MainActivity.this, 
                                 SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL){

            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                orientationChanged = true;
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onOrientationChanged"+ orientation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }};
```

**loadDialog**

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialogDismissed = true;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dialog Dismissed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }});
```

+++++++++++++

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
        if(dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {

            dialog.dismiss();
         }

        //or

         if(dialog != null) {

            dialog.dismiss();
         }

  }
```

**I found out during my study:**

**FirstLoad:**

```
onCreate()
onStart()
onResume()
```

**Change or Orientation:**

```
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()

onCreate()
onStart()
onRestoreInstantState()
onResume()
```

**Activity not visible but not destroyed**

```
onPause()
onStop()
```

**Activity opened from Pause State:**

```
onRestart()
onStart()
onResume()
```

**Activity not visible and destroyed:**

```
onPause()
onStop()
onDestroy()
```

**Activity Destroyed and Re-opened**

```
onCreate()
onStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store them in [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) so that you don't lose them when you restart your application or when the activity reloads.

Edit :

First of all, add this line to your manifest if it is not already done :

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Adding this won't let your activity restart when the orientation changes.
In that case, you can set your *FirstTimeActivityOpened* to true at the beggining of the onCreate() method of your activity and you can set it to false in onDestroy().

Now, you already know when the orientation changes. So when it changes, you just have to prompt your dialog IF it is the first time your app is opened.

Hope this helps

Comment: I agree on some point, how do you identify if is it really first time the app is loaded? like where in the activity's lifecycle method should you know if it is really just orientation change not the exiting of application. thanks

Comment: As much as possible I won't use `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Adding the line I wrote in my answer should make it a lot easier for you.

Comment: I also mean that I would not use `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"`